# Open database and view tables in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

First time sqlite3 user, running windows, and having a hard time getting started.  I have a database in the same folder as my sqlite3.exe application that I want to import into sqlite3 so I can view its tables.

The database is called slash09.db.  I tried .read slash09.db and that made something happen but returns a bunch of garbage characters.  What commands should I try to open/import this and view its tables?

Also, if you know of a good online reference for learning sqlite3 I'd like to read it.  For some reason google hasn't been finding much for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case any tool will do, Firefox has a really nice plugin called [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) that is quite useful for inspecting querying and modifying arbitrary sqlite dbs (not particularly firefox related).

Comment: Okay, downloading now.  Is there a command line command I can use instead though?  I have sqlite3 open and it seems like there should be a really easy way to do this with a single line.

Answer (score 15):

`.read FILENAME` will `Execute SQL in FILENAME`.

If you want to open a `slash09.db` sqlite3 database, simply run:

```
sqlite3 slash09.db
```

For more details on the different commands in the sqlite3 console, try `.help`. For example, you can run `.tables` to enumerate the tables in your database.

Comment: Okay I got the second one to work - I was originally typing that into the sqlite3.exe window instead of the cmd.exe window, ahh.  .read slash09.db still isn't working... returning a lot of errors and garbage characters.  Do you think this is an issue with the database itself?

Comment: upon opening it, run `pragma integrity_check;` If it gives any error than either your database file is corrupted, or it's not an sqlite3 database. More about the pragma here: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check

Comment: with Linux you could run `file slash09.db` to try to figure out what that file contains.

Comment: oh I just read that comment you made again about still using `.read ...`: don't use that. Open you database by running `sqlite3.exe slash09.db` from cmd.exe's prompt.

Answer (score 1):

sqlitebrowser is a nice gui, I use both cl and sqlitebrowser.